# How to give data using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, i'm using editor and wanted to give some paragraph inside the body, But couldn't able to give any type of static paragraph inside the body of the email.

Can anyone help me in giving any static paragraph in the body of the email?

Here is the code:

```
<Modal.Content>
          <Form>
            <Input
              fluid
              type="text"
              label="email"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.value}
            />
            <div>
              <Body
                label="Body"
                name="body"
                value={this.state.body}
                onChange={this.changeBodyHandler}
              />
            </div>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Content>
```

for example: In Body, I want to see like "Greetings of the day!"

[Here is the whole code](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-pasteur-mjrvy).

anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

React is a superset of HTML, since anything that isn't a React component just passes through to the final output to the browser.  So, you can put static content wherever you like in your components.  In fact, you're already doing exactly that in your example with the `div`.

Comment: @Sandhya, is it because `Body` is inside your modal? It shows up for me on your CodePen when I click the button, but not until then.

Comment: To clarify, I just wedged `<div>Test String</div>` above your `Editor` component and it showed up when I clicked the button.

Comment: Yes But i want within the editor, i mean in the body, not outside the body

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by `giving any static paragraph` ?

From your sandbox I see that your `Body` component is just wrapping and `Editor`, and your `Editor` component seems to work as expected.

So what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: In the Body component, i want to display "Greetings of the day "by default. But i couldn't able to display

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the state with your default:

```
this.state = {
  body: "Greetings of the day",
  email: ""
};
```

Comment: if we want to add Some more info with styling then what to do???

Comment: I suggest you add the `draft-js` tag to your question, because it is specific to how their Editor works, not to `React` state management. Unfortunately I don't use that library.

Comment: Sure i'll do that